# Getting the current time millis from device and converting it into a new date with different timezone

Tags: java, android, date, time, timezone

Here the that problem that i'm facing is -

First i have created a date object which will give me current date and time with device timezone i.e

```
Date date = new Date(); // Let say the time zone is India - GMT (+05:30)
The value of date is = "Mon Sep 24 13:54:06 GMT+05:30 2018"
```

No i have a Date formatter using which i have converted the following date object.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss z");
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(loadPreferences(Utility.TIMEZONE_NAME)));
// Here the timezone is Hawaii (GMT-10:00)
```

Now getting the time as per the new time zone i.e., Hawaii

```
String dateS = sdf.format(date); 
// This will give you the date with new timezone - "2018/09/23 22:24:06 GMT-10:00"
```

Now converting this string date to date object as -

```
Date newDate = sdf.parse(dateS);
```

Now the new date which i'm getting is not as per the timezone which i have passed.

```
The value of newDate which i'm getting is = "Mon Sep 24 13:54:06 GMT+05:30 2018" 
//This is device timezone not the one i have set.
```

I have already tried "Z", "z", "X", "ZZ", "ZZZZZ" in the date formatter still no luck.

If any of you have any idea reading this then let me know.

Comment: @amit need solution for android not for .net

Comment: If you just want to transport/pass your `Date`-object around across different time zones then just pass the object. No need to take into account the zones or to format and to reparse. A `Date`-object is just a thin wrapper around the count of milliseconds since 1970-01-01T00Z (worldwide the same!).

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with. And includes a class for a date and time *with* time zone, the `ZonedDateTime` class, which seems to be what you need.

Comment: @OleV.V. yes.. you are right...

Answer (score 1):

Two messages:

- Your expectations are wrong. A `Date` hasn’t got a time zone, it cannot have. So what you are trying to obtain is impossible using `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat` no matter how you write the code.
- The classes `Date`, `SimpleDateFormat` and `TimeZone` are long outdated and poorly designed. Their modern replacements are in java.time, the date and time API introduced in 2014.

### ZonedDateTime

A modern `ZonedDateTime` has a time zone as the name says:

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter 
            = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss z", Locale.US);
    ZonedDateTime nowInHawaii = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Pacific/Honolulu"));
    String dateS = nowInHawaii.format(formatter);
    System.out.println(dateS);
```

Output from this snippet was:

> 2018/09/24 18:43:19 HST

If you want the offset in the output, change the formatter thusly:

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter 
            = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss OOOO", Locale.US);
```

> 2018/09/24 18:45:53 GMT-10:00

### Question: Can I use `java.time` on Android?

Yes, `java.time` works nicely on older and newer Android devices. It just requires at least **Java 6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on new Android devices (from API level 26, I’m told) the modern API comes built-in.
- In Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the modern classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310, where the modern API was first described).
- On (older) Android, use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. Make sure you import the date and time classes from package `org.threeten.bp` and subpackages.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/), explaining how to use `java.time`.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/)
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Answer (score 0):

Please try to debug the value that is coming from 
'loadPreferences(Utility.TIMEZONE_NAME)' and make sure it is same as "US/Hawaii"

Also try to debug by using this -

```
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("US/Hawaii"));
```

Comment: Already did. The value is Pacific/Honolulu which is -10:00 ( Hawaii).