# Kotlin SimpleDateFormat parse wrong timezone

Tags: kotlin, timezone, simpledateformat

My mobile timezone was GMT+7, I have a code to convert a specific date time(GMT+0) to a specific timezone(GMT+3):

```
var strDate = "2020-07-10 04:00:00+0000"
var result: Date?
var dateFormatter = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Jerusalem")
result = dateFormatter.parse(strDate)
```

The problem is result always return "**Fri Jul 10 11:00:00 GMT+07:00 2020**"
But I expected it will return date object "**Fri Jul 10 07:00:00 GMT+03:00 2020**", any idea what's wrong with my code?

Comment: Why are you using an outdated API for date and time operations? Can't you use `java.time` for this? It's obvious that your target time zone does not get applied, but this troublesome API you are using doesn't make it obvious why it isn't applied.

Comment: Related/similar: [Getting the current time millis from device and converting it into a new date with different timezone \[duplicate\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52475409/getting-the-current-time-millis-from-device-and-converting-it-into-a-new-date-wi).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's recommended to use `java.time` and stop using `java.util.Date`, `java.util.Calendar` along with `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` because of problems like this one.

In your code, the target time zone is obviously not applied to the date but it isn't obvious why it isn't.

A different problem might be pattern you are using because your example `String` does not contain any unit of time smaller than seconds but the pattern tries to consider `.SSS` (which made the code fail in the Kotlin Playground).

Switch to `java.time` and handle this with modern classes, such as `OffsetDateTime` for parsing this `String` (it doesn't contain information about a specific time zone, just an offset of zero hours) and `ZonedDateTime` as the target object (this considers a real time zone which may have different offsets depending things like Daylight Saving Time).

You could do it like this:

```kotlin
import java.time.ZoneId
import java.time.ZonedDateTime
import java.time.OffsetDateTime
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter

fun main() {
    // this example is in UTC (+0000 --> no offset / offset of 0 hours)
    var strDate = "2020-07-10 04:00:00+0000"
    // create a formatter that can parse Strings of this pattern
    // ([] represents optional units to be parsed)
    var dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss[.SSS]Z")
    // and parse the String to an OffsetDateTime using this formatter
    var resultOfParsing = OffsetDateTime.parse(strDate, dateFormatter)
    // then print the parsed result
    println(resultOfParsing)
    
    // create the target time zone
    var timeZone = ZoneId.of("Asia/Jerusalem")
    // then use the target zone for a zone shift
    var jerusalemTime: ZonedDateTime = resultOfParsing.atZoneSameInstant(timeZone)
    // and print the result
    println(jerusalemTime)
    // you could use your formatter defined above for a differently formatted output, too
    println(jerusalemTime.format(dateFormatter))
}
```

which outputs (including all intermediate results):

```
2020-07-10T04:00Z
2020-07-10T07:00+03:00[Asia/Jerusalem]
2020-07-10 07:00:00.000+0300
```

Comment: great, thanks @deHaarbut the question is: does it support for android > 5.0 or API level > 21?

Comment: @sontd It was introduced with Java 8 and was supported from Android API level 26, for supporting lower API levels, you had to import a [backport library](https://www.google.com/search?channel=crow2&client=firefox-b-d&q=threeten+abp), but that doesn't seem to be necessary anymore since there's [Android's API Desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support) now.