# Android device system time changes TimeZone of server date string when converting it to Date

Tags: java, android, timezone, simpledateformat

I have to check if difference between time on server and Android device system time more then 1 hour.
For now I have this string from server:

```
2020-08-24T11:50:18.613+0300
```

these is constant I use for SimpleDateFormat:

```
private static final String SYSTEM_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
```

problem is when I try to convert string date to Date class I am getting this:

```
Mon Aug 24 13:50:18 GMT+05:00 2020
```

As I understand +05:00 there is because it is time zone which set at Android device as default. That is how I get this Date:

```
Locale locale =  new Locale("ru","RU");
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(SYSTEM_FORMAT, locale);
df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Moscow"));
Date date = df.parse(serverDate);
```

As you can see even setting time zone to +3 (Moscow time) does not make Date which I expect. I know I can compare it using just string, but demands are to compare Dates

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends. See if you either can use [desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) or add [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project, in order to use java.time, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: Apparently related: (1) [TimeZone problem in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1812700/timezone-problem-in-java) (2) [Getting the current time millis from device and converting it into a new date with different timezone \[duplicate\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52475409/getting-the-current-time-millis-from-device-and-converting-it-into-a-new-date-wi)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like there is some gap in your understanding of Zone-Offset in the date-time string. The date-time string `2020-08-24T11:50:18.613+0300` means it is the date-time at the Zone-Offset of `+0300 hours` i.e. the corresponding date-time string on `UTC` will be `2020-08-24T8:50:18.613+0000`.

Note that `java.util.Date` lacks time-zone and zone-offset information. It just has the number of milliseconds since the epoch of 1 January 1970, 00:00:00 UTC. When you print a `java.util.Date` using an instance of `SimpleDateFormat`, you print the string representing the date-time in the time-zone set into the instance of `SimpleDateFormat`. You can understand it from the following example:

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        // Parse the date-time string to java.util.Date
        String serverDate = "2020-08-24T11:50:18.613+0300";
        final String SYSTEM_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ";
        DateFormat dfSource = new SimpleDateFormat(SYSTEM_FORMAT);
        Date date = dfSource.parse(serverDate);
        System.out.println(date);

        // Get the date-time string for the time-zone of Europe/Moscow from
        // java.util.Date
        Locale locale = new Locale("ru", "RU");
        DateFormat dfTarget = new SimpleDateFormat(SYSTEM_FORMAT, locale);
        dfTarget.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Moscow"));
        System.out.println(dfTarget.format(date));
    }
}
```

I suggest you **stop** using the outdated and error-prone `java.util` date-time API and `SimpleDateFormat`. Switch to the [modern](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html) `java.time` date-time API and the corresponding formatting API (`java.time.format`). Learn more about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**. If your android version is not compliant with Java-8, you can backport using [ThreeTen-BackportCheck](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/). Check [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

## Using modern date-time API:

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        // Given date-time string
        String serverDate = "2020-08-24T11:50:18.613+0300";

        // Date-time formatter
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");

        ZonedDateTime zdtServer = ZonedDateTime.parse(serverDate, formatter);
        System.out.println("Given date-time: " + zdtServer);
        System.out.println("Zone Offset of the given date-time: " + zdtServer.getOffset());

        // Convert it to some other time-zone e.g Etc/UTC
        ZonedDateTime zdtatUTC = zdtServer.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("Etc/UTC"));
        System.out.println("Equivalent date-time at UTC: " + zdtatUTC);

        // Convert it to some other time-zone e.g Europe/London
        ZonedDateTime zdtInLondon = zdtServer.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("Europe/London"));
        System.out.println("Equivalent date-time in London: " + zdtInLondon);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Given date-time: 2020-08-24T11:50:18.613+03:00
Zone Offset of the given date-time: +03:00
Equivalent date-time at UTC: 2020-08-24T08:50:18.613Z[Etc/UTC]
Equivalent date-time in London: 2020-08-24T09:50:18.613+01:00[Europe/London]
```

Note that the modern date-time API has a class called, `ZonedDateTime` which has time-zone information along with the date & time information.

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer. It was really some gap in my understanding of Zone-Offset in the date-time string, but I tried to find answer a lot in here and got what to do only after your answer.

Answer (score 2):

You don't really have a time *zone* but rather an offset.

To correctly convert the `String` you get from a servery, you should use `java.time` instead of the outdated `java.util.Date` or `java.util.Calendar`.

Here's an example that uses a suitable class for your situation (`java.time.OffsetDateTime`):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String stringFromServer = "2020-08-24T11:50:18.613+0300";
    OffsetDateTime timeFromServer = OffsetDateTime.parse(
                        stringFromServer,
                        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")
    );
    
    System.out.println(timeFromServer.format(
            DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss XXX uuuu", Locale.ENGLISH))
    );
}
```

The output of this (the `OffsetDateTime` formatted using a pattern that mimics the one you posted) is

```
Mon Aug 24 11:50:18 +03:00 2020
```

You can use a `ZonedDateTime` as well, but then you will have to add a `ZoneId`, `ZoneId.of("Europe/Moscow")`, most likely...
It can be done like this using the already created `OffsetDateTime timeFromServer`:

```
ZonedDateTime moscowTime = timeFromServer.atZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("Europe/Moscow"));
ZonedDateTime berlinTime = timeFromServer.atZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("Europe/Berlin"));
```

and `System.out`ing them without a special format would give you these lines:

```
2020-08-24T11:50:18.613+03:00[Europe/Moscow]
2020-08-24T10:50:18.613+02:00[Europe/Berlin]
```

**Please note:**
Since there's [API Desugaring for Android](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support) you can use Java 8(+) functionality in API levels below Android 26.

Answer (score 2):

There’s no need to worry about offset from UTC or time zone when comparing times. Comparison across offsets goes smoothly.

### java.time

I am using java.time, the modern Java date and time API. Let’s first define a couple of useful constants:

```
private static final Duration TOLERANCE = Duration.ofHours(1);

private static final DateTimeFormatter serverFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME)
        .appendPattern("XX")
        .toFormatter();
```

Now we can do:

```
    String serverDateTimeString = "2020-08-24T11:50:18.613+0300";
    OffsetDateTime serverTime = OffsetDateTime.parse(serverDateTimeString, serverFormatter);
    System.out.println("Server time: " + serverTime);
    
    ZoneId deviceTimeZone = ZoneId.of("Asia/Yekaterinburg");
    OffsetDateTime deviceTime = OffsetDateTime.now(deviceTimeZone);
    System.out.println("Device time: " + deviceTime);
    
    if (deviceTime.isBefore(serverTime.minus(TOLERANCE)) || deviceTime.isAfter(serverTime.plus(TOLERANCE))) {
        System.out.println("Difference between time on server and Android device system time more than 1 hour");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Difference between time on server and Android device system time 1 hour or less");
    }
```

I have used your string from the question, so we shouldn’t be surprised that the snippet tells us there’s a great difference between the two times when I run it now:

> ```
> Server time: 2020-08-24T11:50:18.613+03:00
> Device time: 2020-08-24T23:08:57.939565+05:00
> Difference between time on server and Android device system time more than 1 hour
> ```

For the sake of the experiment let’s also try setting the device time to the time from your question:

```
    OffsetDateTime deviceTime = OffsetDateTime.of(2020, 8, 24, 13, 50, 18, 0, ZoneOffset.ofHours(5));
```

> ```
> Server time: 2020-08-24T11:50:18.613+03:00
> Device time: 2020-08-24T13:50:18+05:00
> Difference between time on server and Android device system time 1 hour or less
> ```

### Question: Doesn’t java.time require Android API level 26?

java.time works nicely on both older and newer Android devices. It just requires at least **Java 6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26) the modern API comes built-in.
- In non-Android Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the modern classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On older Android either use desugaring or the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. In the latter case make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table)
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.